# Can I upgrade a 54mm portafilter machine to 58mm?

Tags: portafilter

I think this is likely a dumb question but I have a Breville Barista Pro which has a 54mm portafilter.  It seems like all the cool coffee tools come for 58mm portafilters so I was wondering if it was possible to "upgrade" (buy a new one) my 54mm portafilter to a 58mm one for the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, **No**.

The issue is not only with the portafilter, but with the group head that receives the portafilter.
There are several reasons why it is (practically) impossible to do that.
In budget friendly machines such as the the Breville Barista Pro, the brew head is usually some sort of proprietary design of the manufacturer - as opposed to e.g. the Faema E61 brew head who is found on many enthusiast machines.
This makes it practically impossible to find drop-in replacements.

Even if there were replacements, they would usually cost a lot and be very hard to replace, requiring a lot of technical knowledge about how the machine is constructed, not to mention the time required to complete the replacement.

If you're looking for some sort of adapter which enables you to use your 58mm accessories on a 54mm brew head, I must disappoint you as well, I have never heard or seen anything of the sort.

My personal suggestion, should you really be bummed out about the lack of available accessories and really really want to use all the "cool coffee tools", would be to sell your current machine and save money for one with a standard size 58mm brew head. But these machines, especially ones with the aforementioned E61 brew head, start in the ballpark of 1-2 thousand dollars/euros, so that is a decision only you can make.

Comment: Thanks for the candid response - I expected as much.  This was a Father's Day present from my wife and I didn't have any say in the purchase (I also had no idea what I was doing at first so I didn't even realise I should have been distributing my grinds better before tamping.  I'll just get a handheld WDT tool and accept the lost "cool factor."

Comment: I hope your machine will still bring you joy! WDTs are better than those leveler/distribution tools anyways because they allow you to tamp much more evenly. Those levelers you spin around don't distribute the grounds as evenly as they make it look and in some cases this can even cause channeling!

Comment: It has!  Thank you.  I've ordered a WDT and cone to stop the grounds from getting everywhere.  RE Breville, I suppose I should be grateful they haven't yet installed a microchip (ala HP and their toner cartridges) preventing any 3rd party portafilters from working...